# Use $\log(x)$ to calculate $\log(x+1)$

Tags: logarithms, computational-mathematics

Given that I know the value of $\log(x)$, I would like to calculate the value of $\log(x+1)$ on a computer.

I know that I could use the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$, but that uses $x$ rather than $\log(x)$. The reason I do not want to use $x$ directly is because $\log(x)$ can get low values such as $-1000$, and this will cause an underflow.

My question is if there is a way of directly relating $\log(x)$ to $\log(1+x)$?

Comment: $\log{(1+x)}=\log{x}+\log{(1+1/x)}=\log{x}+1/x-1/x^2+...$

Comment: With values of $x$ as low as $e^{-1000}$, you can very very very safely use $\ln(1+x)=x$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Actually if $x = e^{-1000}$, $\log(1+x) = \log(1) = 0$...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which makes me ask: Can the OP's data type represent $e^{-1000}\approx 5\cdot10^{-435}$ at all? That's 100 orders of magnitude smaller than the minimal nonzero `double` ...

Comment: $e^{-1000}$ is zero in double precision.

Comment: @ringø: without much computational effort, $\ln(1+x)=e^{-1000}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed... time to bed!

Comment: What is your desired precision?  Double?

Comment: Why do you want to do this (just for fun or a serious application)? This is relevant to give a good answer.

Comment: @BrianTung double precision.

Comment: @Winther application - I may need to sum 10^9 such values to calculate a partition function.

Comment: What programming environment do you use (do you have access to a built-in $\log(x)$ method)?

Comment: @Winther using python/numpy, which has builtin $log()$, $log1p()$ etc.

Comment: $\log(x)$ in numpy is fast so I suspect that even if you used some approximation (e.g. a Taylor series) to compute $\log(1+x)$ from $\log(x)$ it's not going to speed your code up unless you only deal with very small or very large values of $x$. You should try to time this to check for yourself if you decide to use a different method. See e.g. [this page](http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2015/09/08/SpeedBenchmarks.html) for some benchmarks on computing $\log(x)$ in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $y=\ln x$ and assuming double precision float arithmetic, you can safely approximate

- $\ln(1+x)\approx0$ for $x<4\cdot 10^{-324}$, i.e., for $y<-745$.
- $\ln(1+x)\approx x=e^y$ for $x<2^{-53}$ (that is, if $x^2\ll x$), i.e., for $y<-37$
- $\ln(1+x)\approx \ln x+\frac1x=y+e^{-y}$ for $y>37$
- and in the intermediate range just go ahead and compute $\ln(1+x)=\ln(1+e^y)$.

Actually, most CPUs have a builtin $\ln(1+x)$ suited for this problem

Answer (score 1):

As $x$ is tiny, the Taylor development of $\log(1+x)$ is perfectly appropriate and the requested relation is

$$\log(1+x)\approx x=e^{\log(x)}.$$

You need to take the antilogarithm of the given logarithm.